# spring-data-jpa 3.1.4 returns List<Object[]> long where as spring-data-jpa 2.6.3 retuns biginteger in this use case

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-jdbc

My **pojo** class is :

```
employee{
long empid;
}
```

The table is : `employee ( bigint empid)`
During spring-data-jpa:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    @Query("select * from employee",nativeQuery=true)
    List<Object[]> getEmployeeList();
}
```

Now, when we hit **getEmployeeList()** , earlier with spring-data-jpa(2.6.3) it was returning *biginteger list*. Why with spring-data-jpa 3.1+ it giving long value?

Why it got changed and how to handle it without touching all code?